# How do I use Ansible to add an IP to a Linux hosts file on 18 VMs that iterates from 10.x.x.66..10.x.x.83

Tags: loops, ansible, infrastructure

So, I have a playbook using a hosts file template to update or revert hosts files on 18 specific Linux VMs. The entry which goes at the end of the file looks like:

`10.x.x.66   fooconnect`

This above example would be on the 1st of 18 VMs, the 18th VM would look like:

`10.x.x.83   fooconnect`

Normally, that hostname resolves to a VIP. However, we found during some load testing that it may be beneficial to point each front-end VM to a back-end VM directly. So, my goal is to have a playbook that can update what the hostname resolves to with the above mentioned range, or revert it back to the VIP (reverting back is done using a template only--this part works fine).

What I am unsure about is how to implement this in Ansible. Is there a way to loop through the IPs using jinja2 template "for loops?" Or maybe using lineinfile with some loop magic?

Here is my Ansible role example. For the moment I am using a dirty shell command to create my IP list...open to suggestions for a better way to implement this.

```
- name: Add a line to a hosts file using a template
  template:
    src: "{{ srcfile }}"
    dest: "{{ destfile }}"
    owner: "{{ own_var }}"
    group: "{{ grp_var }}"
    mode: "{{ mode_var }}"
    backup: yes

- name: Get the IPs
  shell: "COUNTER=66;for i in {66..83};do echo 10.x.x.$i;((COUNTER++));done"
  register: pobs_ip

- name: Add a line
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/hosts
    line: "{{item}}    fooconnect"  #Ideally would want "item" to just be one IP and not 
    insertafter: EOF                #the entire list as it would be like this.
  loop: "{{pobsips}}"
```

VARs file:

```
pobsips:
  - "{{pobs_ip.stdout}}"
```

Comment: Do you want all those IPs to resolve to the same hostname?

Comment: Yes. The hostname is the same, just a different IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a `shell` task, we can improvise it and create the range of IP addresses using `set_fact` with `range`. Once we have the range of IP addresses in a "list", we can loop `lineinfile` with that and achieve this.

Example:

```yaml
    - name: create a range of IP addresses in a variable my_range
      set_fact:
        my_range: "{{ my_range|default([]) + [ '10.1.1.' ~ item ] }}"
      loop: "{{ range(66, 84)|list }}"
    - name: Add a line to /etc/hosts
      lineinfile:
        path: /etc/hosts
        line: "{{ item }} fooconnect"
        insertafter: EOF
      loop: "{{ my_range }}"
```

---

**Updated answer:**

There is another approach if we want to append *only 1 line* into the `/etc/hosts` file of each host with incrementing IP addresses.

- For this we can use the `ipmath` of [ipaddr filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters_ipaddr.html) to get the next IP address for given IP address.
- Use `ansible_play_hosts` to get the list of hosts on which play is running
- Set an index variable `index_var` and `when` condition to update file only when the `ansible_hostname` or `inventory_hostname` matches.
- Run playbook serially and only once on a host per run using `serial` and `run_once` flags.

Let's consider an example inventory file like:

```
[group_1]
host1
host2
host3
host4
...
```

Then in playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: group_1
  serial: 1

  vars:
    start_ip: 10.1.1.66

  tasks:
    - name: Add a line to /etc/hosts
      lineinfile:
        path: "/tmp/hosts"
        line: "{{ start_ip|ipmath(my_idx) }} fooserver"
        insertafter: EOF
      loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
      loop_control:
        index_var: my_idx
      run_once: true
      when: item == inventory_hostname
```

Comment: Thank you for the Answer. It is mostly working the way I want. The only outstanding issue is that it is adding the entire IP range into each hosts file instead of only adding one IP per host. In other words.

```Server1 hosts file should contain... 10.x.x.66   fooconnect
Server2 ...                                         10.x.x.67   fooconnect
Server3 ...                                         10.x.x.68   fooconnect```
and so on.
Apologies if that was not clear. But using the range in the loop worked really well.

Comment: I updated the answer, this should achieve what you need. Though execution will be slower due to `serial` flag.

Comment: Thank you again. This update did indeed allow me to achieve my goal and I have accepted the answer. Appreciate your time.